# using primary key as foreign key in mysql for big tables

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my mysql named "cats", this table have 'cat_id','cat_parent','cat_name' and I decide to have another table named "cats_details", that have 'cat_id','cat_description','cat_keywords', Etc. because my categories can be nested (each main category can have unlimited number of sub categories and each sub category can have unlimited number of sub sub categories , ...) and number of categories may reach over 1000. and I need list them in some page :P. so I think it is best way to have 2 tables, one for listing categories and searching in its names and another one for having details about categories. so my question is what is the best way for this case?

**1-** use 'cat_id' of "cats_details" as primary key for itself and foreign key for "cats" table.

**2-** make a column named 'id' (int auto increment) for primary key of "cats_details" and another column 'cat_id' in "cats_details" as foreign key for "cats" table.

what of this solutions are more faster for big number of categories and big number of visitors?

**NOTE:** I only use JOIN in category details page, not in listing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What scalability numbers are you expecting? Have you done any preliminary capacity planning?

Denormalization optimizes a database for reads by creating redundant data but insertions or deletions can cause data inconsistency if not uniformly applied to all redundant copies of the data in the database (hence there is some maintenance overhead as maintaining data consistency is now the job of the application ).

Unless you are looking at millions of rows in your tables, with current hardware it doesn't matter - normalization is fine.

I am assuming that cat_id is an int or Guid. The primary key will be a clustered index and make reads fast hence Option 1 will result in faster reads. Since you will mostly be doing reads/Joins by the primary key, option 2 is less efficient as cat_id in option 2 will most probably be a non-clustered index (although inserts/deletes will be faster in this case).

Comment: in one article I'd read: all tables must have an auto increment primary key although when you use them for be a part of another table and foreign key must be another column.

Comment: but with your informations I decide to use my primary key as foreign key. cause I need to JOIN "cats" table to itself (for getting child categories of each category) so its better it be low weight. what is your opinion about this?

Comment: For getting child categories: A self-join is more efficient than a nested query (where join condition is specified in a WHERE clause). You can use a query performance analyzer to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at normalization of tables. This should solve your problem. A good link might be this one: http://www.troubleshooters.com/littstip/ltnorm.html but any google search on table normalization should help you...

Comment: I know about normalizations. and its levels (1,2,3,4,5,6). but my question is "is it right to use primary key as foreign key in mysql or its better too have a primary and a foreign key"